# Creating contained users for Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, contained-database

What's the difference between these two commands?

```
CREATE USER abc FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
CREATE USER abc FOR  EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

Comment: The difference is that one of them isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

As mustaccio mentioned, `CREATE USER abc FOR  EXTERNAL PROVIDER` is invalid syntax due to the `FOR`. `FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` is the correct syntax. But I don't think you came across the invalid syntax on accident, it seems some edge case uses of certain components of SQL Server have a bug that generates this incorrect syntax, at least from my research:

1. [SqlPackage.exe - CREATE USER [] FOR EXTERNAL PROVIDER;](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38373595-sqlpackage-exe-create-user-name-for-external)
2. [Azure SQL Drop and Create AAD User During Every Deploy - FOR EXTERNAL PROVIDER](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/961513/azure-sql-drop-and-create-aad-user-during-every-de.html)
3. [Using Azure DevOps DACPAC task to run a SQL command on the master database of Azure SQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291546/using-azure-devops-dacpac-task-to-run-a-sql-command-on-the-master-database-of-az)

Comment: Nope; disagree; Both are valid and I just checked in our environment with a valid AD user, to be 100% sure  !!